# Gradle error: Could not determine a usable local IP for this machine

Tags: react-native, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I got this error when building react native android app within Windows Subsystem Linux

Any idea how to resolve that please?

**Update**

Windows build 14955 (from Windows Insider Program) fixed this issue

Comment: I saw this bug on mac and fixed it by disable ipv6 and delete a default ipv6 route in `netstat -nr`. Hope this can help someone.

Comment: I get this issue when trying to build using Gradle for ARM via qemu-binfmt docker containers.  In case anyone else is attempting the same as me, the solution is to add `--network host` to the docker-run arguments.

Answer (score 2):

Appears to be a known issue with WSL, solved by upgrading to a newer windows insider build.

See https://github.com/Microsoft/BashOnWindows/issues/850 for more info